# INSERT INTO for each SELECT returns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have made a SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE (field1 IS NOT NULL AND field2 IS NOT NULL)
```

It returns 2 columns (the table doesn't have a primary key), now I want to insert the data into another table for each row the query returns (with additional data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into some_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT field1, field2, 'additional data'
FROM table1 
WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL AND field2 IS NOT NULL
```